# Match/Compare two PBKDF2 hashed values

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, pbkdf2

Below is my scenario.

I have developed register(signup) and login feature for my website.

UI is developed in AngularJS 2 and backed API are in Spring Boot with POstgreSQL as DB.

---

**While register**, I accept two parameters (username and password), my requirement is when my front-end is calling backend API, I hash the raw password with PBKDF2(random salt) and send it to back-end */register* API, as below:

```
{
  "username":"test",
  "password":"##passwordhashvalue##"
}
```

On Server Side, I store these values in DB.

---

**While Login,** I again follow same from front-end and send it to back-end */login* API as below:

```
{
  "username":"test",
  "password":"##passwordhashvalue##"
}
```

On Server Side, To authorize the username/password, I have two hashed password values to compare, One which I received as input and other from database. In normal scenarios we usually have one raw value and other hashed value. **Is there any way I can achieve this to match/compare two PBKDF2 hashed values with random salt?**

Thank you very much.